# How can I center the logo in my navbar and keep it in line?

Tags: html, css

I made this navigation but have several problems.

1. header pic comes after the nav but I want navigation to be on the header.
2. I want navigation to be sticky at the same time. That means when I scroll down, the navigation comes down with the same way and does not change.
3. how can I make best responsive?
4. how can I optimize it better in general?

```css
nav {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 1.5em 30em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 45%;
  height: 10vh;
  /* border: 3px dotted red; */
  z-index: 999;
}

.navContainer {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #d6d6d6;
  border-radius: 10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  /* border: 3px dotted green; */
}

.navContainer a {
  color: #1b1b1b;
}

.logoContaienr img {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
}

.anmeldungsContainer {
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #d6d6d6;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #034078;
  margin-left: 20px;
  /* border: 3px dotted blue; */
}

.anmeldungsContainer li {
  padding-top: 0.5em;
}

.anmeldungsContainer a {
  color: #d6d6d6;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  margin: 0 2em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bolder;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="navContainer">
    <div class="linksMenuContainer">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Kurse</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ernährung</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="logoContaienr">
      <img src="../Img/Logo.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="rechtsMenuContainer">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Abos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Trainer</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="anmeldungsContainer">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Anmeldung</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Why do you have two elements with flexbox applied?

Comment: Dear @Sasan... There are a lots of issues with the code when it comes to using good CSS... Let me modify it a bit as per my understanding of what you want to achieve :)

Comment: Dear @ImranRafiqRather. that is very kind of you. Thanks alot

Comment: Please check this one : I just made some modification :https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/MWjXqpQ

Comment: If there is anything else you require, just let me know :) And if it works I will answer it accordingly :)

Comment: Just refresh the page codepen.io once... So that the changes are reflected :)

Comment: You may require small changes as per your design :) If possible share you design image with me as well... So that I get better idea about what you are trying to make :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the code overall as per my understanding of the requirement.

**Please visit:** https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/MWjXqpQ

Some major changes : ( The commented stuff is what we no longer require)

```
nav {
/*   position: absolute; */
/*   margin: 1.5em 30em; */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
/*   width: 45%; */
  height: 50px;

  border: 3px dotted red;
/*   z-index: 999; */
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

Comment: first of all, thank you very much. 
How can navigation and login button be side by side and also everything stay in the middle

Comment: Hmm, I got it... I will update on the main code :)

Comment: Thank you @Imran Rafiq Rather

Comment: Hey @ImranRefiqRather. What is the best way to Responsive this menu?

Comment: Best way would be to use a Hamburger menu and logo on navbar. And once the handburger icon is clicked show the other links :)